# How to Pass CSS A CSS property in b class in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
const Styles = StyleSheet.create({
    A: {
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        color: 'red'
    },
    B: {        
        ...A
    },
)}
```

Property 'A' doesn't exist, js engine: hermes. How to Pass CSS A CSS property in b class in react native currently show in this error

Answer (score 0):

I think there is **no direct approach available to access the sibling styles** in the StyleSheet.create method.

For a such requirement achievement, you can **create different StyleSheet objects and inherit them** when needed.

**For Example**

```
const stylesA = StyleSheet.create({
  mainView: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'grey',
  },
});

// accessing the styleA properties here
const root = StyleSheet.create({
  ...stylesA,
  header: {
    ...stylesA.mainView,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: yes but it's not right way because every time use Stylesheet. Create in single class

Stylesheet. Create use only single time not a multi time

Comment: I think you can use multi times there is no issue with creating multiple styles..

Comment: Check the changes in code, now you can access styles in your screen from one root stylesheet object only.